# Создается несколько приложений при установке(android)

Tags: android

обнаружил, что при установке приложения создается несколько экранов, как это исправить?
Возможно не так настроил файл манифеста, поэтому добавлю его сюда:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.jone1.graciaonline">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <meta-data android:name="android.security.net.config"
        android:resource="@xml/network_security_config" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Gracia online"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".fragment14"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            android:label="@string/about_title">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: У вас все Activity помечены как загрузочный активити, в этом и проблема

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите на этот код. Только SignInActivity обладает следующими параметрами:
`android.intent.action.MAIN` означает, что это действие является точкой входа приложения, то есть при запуске приложения это действие создается.

`CATEGORY_LAUNCHER` означает, что он должен появиться в Launcher как приложение верхнего уровня

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".activities.SignInActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activities.SignUpActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.HomeActivity"
        android:label="Главная"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activities.SmartphoneActivity" />        

</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Убрал из 3 активити строчку:

```
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Замени следующим образом

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<meta-data android:name="android.security.net.config"
    android:resource="@xml/network_security_config" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Gracia online"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <activity android:name=".fragment14"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

</application>
```